Can't retrieve tags for jenkins build, using git parameter plugin
I have added a git parameter plugin named as TAG, which is supposed to list all tags present in my Gitlab repository. I also have added default tag value as v1.0.0. There are other set of parameters too, like choice, string parameters which I use in my build script. When I choose build with parameters option, In the drop-down to list tags, it just shows a loader and after sometime shows error with a build timeout. 
Now, There is another jenkins server which also builds same build script and branch, which lists all tags correctly. Same version of jenkins is used in both ec2 : 2.346.1 and with same plugins. Only difference is in the type of ec2's. Here I use Ubuntu 16.04 and in other instance which build is fine uses arch.
I updated git version 2.7 to 2.34.1 which was the git version in the other instance which works correctly. I did so since its the only difference found in the build script logs and git seems too old. But this also doesn't seem to solve the issue. I am able to build, but every time to default version. Another thing I found is that, even the beginning stage logs of build seems too slow, to display in console output (4 mins), which normally is just git repo access operations.
I have also tried to access tags in my workspace, which correctly gets listed. All plugins used in jenkins are identical in both ec2's . I don't understand what I am missing here.

Have you considered a networking issue with traffic from your Jenkins server to the Git server? Validate your routing and security groups a configured properly.

Not yet. Haven't thought about networking side to come in play here. WIll consider that.

Hey @NoamHelmer,Sorry for the delay. Prioritised some other work. Back to this, I have checked for networking issue with traffic from Jenkins server to Git server. It seems to work fine. I have tried manually fetching tags using commands in my ec2 repo. They seem to be working fine, as said above . Now, I am wondering what else is going wrong here. Now, All I am able to do is build on default value given for git parameter plugin. Nothing else seem to show up so I can't checkout to any other tags too
